# How to enable Long Term Validation (LTV) with pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox, signature

I using pdfbox to signature but when check signature in acrobat  reader has result: Long term validation(LTV) not enable
[image]

And this is my source code

```
@Override
public byte[] sign(InputStream content) throws IOException {
    try {
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) this.certificateChain[0];
        ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSA").build(this.privateKey);
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build()).build(sha1Signer, cert));
        gen.addCertificates(new JcaCertStore(Arrays.asList(this.certificateChain)));
        CMSProcessableInputStream msg = new CMSProcessableInputStream(content);
        CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(msg, false);

        //add timestamp if TSA is available
        TimeStampManager timeStampManager = new TimeStampManager();
        signedData = timeStampManager.addSignedTimeStamp(signedData, timeStampToken);
        return signedData.getEncoded();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Write log error sign to table Log in DB
        // TODO: 10/19/20  
        
        //throw new IOException cause a SignatureInterface
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

TimestampManager.addSignedTimeStamp

```
/**
 * Extend cms signed data with TimeStamp first or to all signers
 *
 * @param signedData Generated CMS signed data
 * @param timeStampToken TimeStampToken
 * @return CMSSignedData Extended CMS signed data
 * @throws IOException, TSPException
 */
public CMSSignedData addSignedTimeStamp(CMSSignedData signedData, TimeStampToken timeStampToken) throws IOException, TSPException {
    SignerInformationStore signerStore = signedData.getSignerInfos();
    List<SignerInformation> signersWithTimeStamp = new ArrayList<>();
   
    for (SignerInformation signer : signerStore.getSigners()) {
        // This adds a timestamp to every signer (into his unsigned attributes) in the signature.
        signersWithTimeStamp.add(signTimeStamp(signer, timeStampToken));
    }

    // new SignerInformationStore have to be created cause new SignerInformation instance
    // also SignerInformationStore have to be replaced in a signedData
    return CMSSignedData.replaceSigners(signedData, new SignerInformationStore(signersWithTimeStamp));
}

/**
 * Extend CMS Signer Information with the TimeStampToken into the unsigned Attributes.
 *
 * @param signer information about signer
 * @return information about SignerInformation
 * @throws IOException
 */
private SignerInformation signTimeStamp(SignerInformation signer, TimeStampToken timeStampToken) throws IOException, TSPException {
    AttributeTable unsignedAttributes = signer.getUnsignedAttributes();

    ASN1EncodableVector vector = new ASN1EncodableVector();
    if (unsignedAttributes != null) {
        vector = unsignedAttributes.toASN1EncodableVector();
    }

    byte[] token = timeStampToken.getEncoded();
    ASN1ObjectIdentifier oid = PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signatureTimeStampToken;
    ASN1Encodable signatureTimeStamp = new Attribute(oid, new DERSet(ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(token)));
    vector.add(signatureTimeStamp);
    Attributes signedAttributes = new Attributes(vector);

    // replace unsignedAttributes with the signed once
    return SignerInformation.replaceUnsignedAttributes(signer, new AttributeTable(signedAttributes));
}
```

I want signature auto enable LTV same this
[image]

Please help auto enable LTV in signature with pdfbox in my source code!
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the `AddValidationInformation.java` example from the source code download?

Comment: i try AddValidationInformation 
AddValidationInformation validation = new AddValidationInformation();
File outFile = File.createTempFile("outPdf", ".pdf");
validation.validateSignature(inFile, outFile);

but has error: No Issuer Certificate found for Cert: 'CN=AMANO-TSU-320, OU=Thales TSS ESN:D420-2845-7C98, OU=e-timing TSA, O=AMANO Corporation, L=Yokohama, ST=Kanagawa, C=JP', i.e. Cert 'CN=SECOM TimeStamping CA3, O="SECOM Trust Systems CO.,LTD.", C=JP' is missing in the chain

Cause cert and timestamp do not match because cert i buy from secom and timestamp i buy from amano ?

Comment: It means your TSA server doesn't return the whole chain and the certificate does not tell where to get it. Either tell your TSA to return the whole chain, or download the missing certificate yourself and add it when needed, i.e. change the example code so that this certificate is used when needed. Signing and timestamping doesn't have to be from the same vendor.

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor please help me fix this issue.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i send information
Link down file signed pdf: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BNgoU6HtJw_aStO8MKTlzZYR0H1omZty/view?usp=sharing
TSA certificate: amano timestamp
Thanks

Comment: Here's the LTV file that I created with the `AddValidationInformation.java` example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WcaVZY-WxSJRMgB_fikde5wnm6-Dv8Bs/view  But your file doesn't have a timestamp signature from Amano.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr please show me your code enable LTV with AddValidationInformation.java
Thanks you

Comment: I really did nothing else than to call AddValidationInformation like you did and with the current version 2.0.23. The error you showed in your comment makes sense, but it would have come from a different file. I think you mixed up something. Your screenshots also shows a file that has no timestamp. (The line above the red rectangle) You need to send upload the file that you get AFTER the step with amano.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks you, my code is working. before i used version 2.0.21

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please delete your question or answer it yourself.

Comment: timeStampToken is not declared in the sign() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
My issue when i use pdf-example version 2.0.21
Then i update version pdf-example to 2.0.23 then my issue is resolve

Comment: You should at least mention that you use `AddValidationInformation`. There is no "auto enable LTV" in the examples.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr can you please point me to an up-to-date example for addValidtionInformation? I'm dealing with this issue at the moment and I think I'm missing some crucial step! Thanks